# In git, how do I pull from my branch's parent branch?

Tags: git

In git, how do I pull from my branch's parent branch?

Here's my setup:

```
$ git branch -a
  develop
* feature/myBranch
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/feature/myBranch
  remotes/origin/master
```

BitBucket shows that develop has a change to a file that I need to pull into my workspace. I've committed other changes to my workspace, but I can't build or commit without this change.

Here's what I've tried:

```
$ git fetch
$ git pull
Already up to date. (I knew this wouldn't work)
$ git pull origin
Already up to date.
$ git pull origin
Already up to date.
$ git pull origin feature/myBranch
From https://myServer.com/myData
* branch          feature/myBranch -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

Develop is my parent branch, so it shouldn't be hard to do.

Comment: What's a parent branch? Commits can have parent commits, but I've never heard of a parent branch before.

Comment: You've got your terminology mixed up. You probably either want to merge develop into your branch, or rebase yours onto develop.

Comment: You can pull from a repository, but you can't pull from a branch.  Perhaps you are wanting to cherry-pick commits from the other branch, reset to the other branch,  or ??  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Whilst having `feature/myBranch` checked out, try `git merge develop`? Or rebase `git rebase develop`.

Comment: Maybe you just want to rebase on `develop`

Comment: Maybe I have my terminology mixed up, and maybe that's why I don't understand how to do this. But the branch called feature/myBranch was branched off the develop branch. And develop has a change that I need. And I don't know how to pull it into my workspace.

Comment: It really sounds like you just want `git rebase develop`

Comment: My coworkers are telling me to "pull the changes onto my branch." So that makes me skeptical that rebase is the right option, but I've never head a satisfactory explanation of what rebase does, or what problem it solves.

Comment: @MiguelMunoz it sounds like you might want to watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ffBJ4sVUb4

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't want to make any changes on the develop branch. The change I need is already there. Does that clarify my situation?

Comment: @MiguelMunoz The suggestions made do not affect develop

Comment: @evolutionxbox CodeCaster suggested I might want to "rebase yours onto develop." Please correct me if I'm wrong, but this sounds like it would change the develop branch.

Comment: @CodeCaster It sounds like I want to merge develop onto my branch. How do I do that?

Comment: @MiguelMunoz ---->  _"Whilst having `feature/myBranch` checked out, try `git merge develop`? Or rebase `git rebase develop`"_

Comment: @evolutionxbox I don't know what a rebase does. But I want to bring a change from the develop branch (from which my branch originated) onto myBranch. Does rebase do that? Does merge do that? Am I not clear about what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: You are clear about what you're trying to accomplish. My comment answers it. Also watch the video I've linked so you can understand what rebase does, what a commit is, and what a merge does.

Comment: `git merge develop` just gives me an "Already up to date" message.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't update your local develop. Try `git checkout develop; git merge origin/develop; git checkout -`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many terms in Git that are confusing, and though it's obvious what you mean from your question, based on the discussion in the comments I think it's important to get the proper terminology.

You used the term "parent branch" to mean `develop` because that's the branch you created your branch `myBranch` from, which makes sense in "English". In Git though, branches are just pointers to a commit. So it's better to think, "I created `myBranch` from commit X." Or, "I created `myBranch` from `develop` when `develop` was pointing to commit X." It's actually the commit X that matters, not `develop`. This is why the concept of "parent branch" doesn't exist in Git.

The next thing to understand is your local branch `develop` doesn't stop pointing to it's tip commit until you tell it to. This is why when you tried to update `myBranch` by merging in `develop` it didn't work, as you explained:

> `git merge develop` just gives me an "Already up to date" message.

Usually people update their own copy of `develop` by doing something like this:

```
git checkout develop
git pull
```

And at that point your local copy of `develop` will be the same as your copy of `origin/develop` which will be the same as the remote version of `develop`. After doing that you can then merge `develop` into your branch to bring in the desired changes.

Note, I personally recommend not using `develop` anymore for this very reason- because it goes out of date quickly and you'll surely forget to keep updating it. Instead you can regularly use `git fetch` to update your "remote tracking branches" (those that start with `origin/*`) and then you can create all of your new branches from `origin/develop` instead, like this:

```
git fetch
git switch -c myNewBranch origin/develop --no-track
```

When it's time to update your branch, like you wish to do now, you can use:

```
git checkout myBranch
git fetch
git merge origin/develop
```

If you're willing to start doing that you can just delete your local copy of `develop` and always use `origin/develop` from now on.

As for the other way of updating your branch, using rebase, the way it's phrased:

> rebase `myBranch` onto the lastest `develop` branch

does make it seem like you are updating the `develop` branch, but you are actually just going to update your own branch. The reason the word "onto" is used is because with rebase, you are going to take some range of commits from your branch, and "replay" them "onto" some other commit. (Note when we say "replay" you can think of this as "rewrite" those commits to make brand new commits with new IDs.)

To rebase, you could do this:

```
git checkout myBranch
git fetch
git rebase origin/develop
```

Or, a shorthand that automatically does the checkout for you:

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/develop myBranch
```

In words, that says:

> Take all of the commits on myBranch that are not reachable by origin/develop and replay all of them, one by one, **onto** origin/develop.

The end result is `myBranch` will be rewritten to look like you just branched off of the latest `develop` right now and made your commits, with the exception that your commits will keep their original author and author dates, so those dates might actually be older than the latest commits showing on your branch after those. (But every commit actually has 2 dates, so the committer dates will be "now".)

So now we know you can update your branch by *merging in* the latest `develop`, or by *rebasing onto* the latest `develop`. For completeness, note you can also do both of these by using the `pull` command if you wish:

```
git checkout myBranch

# do the same as fetch, and then merge in origin/develop
# This assumes you did not override the default behavior of the "pull" command,
# which is "merge" by default.
git pull origin develop

# OR
# do the same as fetch and rebase
git pull --rebase origin develop
```

Note the first option is what has already been provided by [Sutariya Sumit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73776854/184546). This is a fine way to accomplish what you want, and is why:

> My coworkers are telling me to "pull the changes onto my branch."

That being said, my personal preference is not to use the pull command, but instead use the explicit merge or rebase commands provided above, as you can inspect what you got with the fetch before doing the merge or rebase.

Answer (score 2):

first you are on **myBranch**
if not then write a command

> git checkout myBranch

Now you can take a pull from develop using this command

> git pull origin develop

Answer (score -2):

You can create a `Pull Request` and `Merge` from `develop` to `feature/myBranch` to be sync with latest changes in `develop` branch.

Comment: _"Pull Request & Merge"_? Git doesn't have a pull-request feature (not the same as `git request-pull`)

Comment: I can't get a pull-request approved until my build works, and I can't fix my build without this change, so a pull-request is out of the question.

Comment: Don't use `inline code` to highlight random terms.

Comment: This approach is also fundamentally wrong. The "develop" or main or default or shared branch is the shared source of truth, the stable branch, whatever you want to call it. Pull requests go _into_ that branch. They don't originate _from_ there. If you're working on a topic/feature, you do so on your own branch. If you then need changes from develop, you merge origin/develop into your own branch. Only when your feature is finished, you create a pull request from your branch into develop.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).